# column to row but keep the same the previous row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have multiple block of data as below and I want to transform it from column to row.
Im new to excel so I hope you guys can help me with.

e.g:
input:

```
A AA 1 2 3 4 5
B BB 1 2 3 4 5
C CC 1 2 3 4 5
```

expect output:

```
A AA 1
     2
     3
     4
     5
B BB 1
     2
     3
     4
     5
C CC 1
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

Comment: A AA in the same cell?

Comment: no, they are in different cells , but I solve this problem